# How to execute sql file in play framework 2.0?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an .sql file that needs to be run every day on scheduler. I found that schedulers are done via Akka. Now how to execute an sql file in play framework 2? Ebean only allows me to execute single query.

Comment: @Joe Nope, I've put it on cron

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use a raw JDBC connection, and use the ScriptRunner class provided here: https://gist.github.com/831762/

Play provides a helper to get a JDBC connection:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = play.db.DB.getConnection();
```

and then:

```
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(con, autoCommit, stopOnerror);
runner.setDelimiter(";", true);
runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile.sql")));
```